# Mayer-Vietoris for $\mathbb C\mathbb P^n$?

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology

Does anyone have any idea of how calculating the De Rham cohomology $H^k(\mathbb C\mathbb P^n)$ of the complex projective space using Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: Google certainly does: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=de+rham+cohomology+mayer+vietoris+complex+projective+space

Comment: @Adam, by sure that was the first thing I've done, if I had found something useful I wouldn't have asked here...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take $U=\mathbb{C}P^n\setminus\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ where $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ is the obvious inclusion in to $\mathbb{C}P^n$, i.e the set of points in homogeneous coordinates with non-zero last coordinate. Take $V=\mathbb{C}P^n\setminus\{[0:0:\ldots:0:1]\}$ in homogenous coordinates.

Can you find homotopy equivalences between $U, V, U\cap V$ and some spaces which you know the cohomology of (you will need to use an inductive argument here for one of these spaces)?

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll think about it.. If I write a proof I'll post it..

Comment: @PtF If you do write the proof, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question. If you get stuck on the way, feel free to ask for any more hints.

Comment: Ok, thanks again @Daniel =D

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $\mathbb{C}P^n=e^0\cup e^2 \cup \dots\cup e^{2n}$ (cell complex, $e^i$ are balls) then the intersection is just the boundary of balls. Also, for $k=0,1$ we can just use Hurewicz that states $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^n)^{ab}=H^1(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ and that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is path-connected the get that $H^0(\mathbb{C}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I'll think about it too.. =D