# Cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^k$ using Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to calculate the cohomology groups of $\mathbb{CP}^k$ using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. However, I can't think of a suitable pair of open subsets to work with.

What direction should I proceed in?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Two affine opens won't cover $\mathbb{CP}^k$ for $k>1$.

Comment: Whoops, of course. In any case there's a previous thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413802/mayer-vietoris-for-mathbb-c-mathbb-pn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Maybe try to set $U$ to be a small nhbd of a point $p$ and $V$ to be $\mathbb{CP}^n-\{p\}$. Now $V\simeq \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ and $U\cap V\simeq S^{2n-1}$, if I did everything correctly but I'm not sure. Then, the argument is just a work of manipulating mappings, including finding kernels and images.